# How to see what is on the other monitors when you only have access to one?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Suppose I have 3 monitors but 2 are in another room. I want to be able to see and interact with what is on the other two from only the main monitor (to move window around). Any way to accomplish that? On a Windows environment. No Internet Access and no network access. And no hardware modification, only software allowed.

Comment: Is there any possibility of having four monitors? 2 in the room, 2 outside? Then you could clone each one to the outside.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, why do you have two monitors in the other room?

Comment: It's a security setup. One person per room watching one monitor with multiple window in it. I need to arrange the windows correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold Shift, press and hold the Window key, and press right or left arrow. The window will switch monitors. Interact with it as you wish then send it back.